# Getting name of specific object from an array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that essentially looks like this after `console.log(array)`:

```
[Fruits,Vegetables]
    0 : Fruits
         apple : red
         banana: yellow
    1 : Vegetables
         tomato: red
```

I need to check the array to see if an index is a fruit or vegetable however when I try `array[0]` I get the object itself and not "Fruits".

I know I can get to "yellow" by calling `array[0].banana` and getting "apple" and "banana" by calling `Object.keys(array[0])` but I don't know how to get to "Fruits". Also I only have access to the object and not where the object is made if that makes any difference.

**EDIT/NOTE:**
For those who are asking, I do not have access to the javascript object code itself because this is actually done on a larger scale with real data that is added to the object in several places dynamically. All I can do is call the object. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Thank you to all who replied, although none of the proposed solutions worked I ended up using one of the attributes in the object to distinguish the Fruits from the Vegetables instead.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for the prototype of your objects. Have you tried `Object.getPrototypeOf(array[0])`?

Comment: `if (array.indefOf(Fruits) > -1) console.log(array[array.indeOf(Fruits)]) ` Does it help you?

Comment: Please show the actual JavaScript object representation of your data.

Answer (score 0):

For the key, you need to access the result of the Object.keys result:

```
Object.keys(array[0])[0]
```

```js
var array = [{ Fruits: { apple: 'red', banana: 'yellow' } }, { Vegetables: { tomato: 'red' } }];
 
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(array[0])[0], 0, 4)+ '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `Fruits` and `Vegetables` aren't keys in an object

Comment: hm, the object is missing, i could only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the code itself (instead of the console log)? I'm not sure what your requirements are but you could use an object instead of an array with fruits and vegetables as the keys. Consider the following:

```
var object = {
    fruits:[
        {
            apple: 'red'
        }
    ]
};
```

If you're looking to abstract the type from an array that's a mix of the two you could do something like this instead:

```
var array = [
    {
        color: 'red',
        name: 'apple',
        type: 'fruit'
    }
]
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
// For getting all the keys and value of a json object

for (var key in array) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = array[key];
        var e = array[key];
        console.log(key+" : "+val);
        }
    for (var key in e) {
        if (e.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = e[key];
            console.log(key+" : "+val);
        }
    }
}
```

Try above code, if you are looking for an object fruits, you can add condition accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you this helped me find another way to solve the issue although not in the way I intended.